# Call a function recursively with same argument

Tags: swift

I have the following function

```
func doSomeWork(x: Bool)
{
  // parse and do stuff;
  ....

  if true
  {
    // call the same function with the same argument it was called with
     doSomeWork()
  }
  else
  {
    return
  }
}
```

So I am trying to figure out how do I call doSomeWork() function again with the same argument it was invoked with originally?

Comment: Does `doSomeWork(x)` not work?

Comment: oh wow, yes it did. I didn't know that. Would you be able to explain why that worked in a short answer?

Comment: I tried, but I'm not sure which part is confusing for you. Let me know if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: yeah, I think I was just over thinking it. It makes since now looking at it a little harder. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function `doSomeWork` takes a `Bool`. Since `x` is a Bool, you can pass it in: `doSomeWork(x)` just like `doSomeWork(true)` or `doSomeWork(false)`.